# is bitkingdom.org legit?

Tags: fraud

My grand father invested in a bitcoin scheme few years back he died recently.In his whatsapp he had all details about this investment. I Have no idea about how this works. I tried looking around for the site mentioned in the DMs but couldn't  find any trace of the site "https://www2.bitkingdom.org" "https://www.bitkingdom.org". I just want clarification whether my grandpa was mugged or he made it big? Any help I would really appreciate.

thank you,
jabes

Answer (score 2):

A quick websearch found me a review on [BehindMLM](https://behindmlm.com/mlm-reviews/bitkingdom-review-malaysian-mmm-global-ponzi-clone/). The site indicates that BitKingdom was a multi-layer marketing scheme. Unless your grandfather happened to be one of the first investors and actually cashed out, the funds are probably lost.

Disclaimer: I'm only familiar in passing with BehindMLM, but they had a lot of useful background information on BitClub and OneCoin in the past. I have not further verified this initial take.

Comment: thank you for the info. and No! my grand father had not cashed out large amount in  past 4 years. He had nasty returns from different investments, this was one of those. I was thinking I would be a millionaire after I cash out the money. But it seems all that investment went down the drain. he should have brought another house..!!!